# Number of elements of command line arguments

Tags: c++, c

I have a problem with command-line arguments.
I need to write a program that will count the size of elements of each command-line argument passed in argv array.
Simple code looks like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("%lu\n", sizeof(argv[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I understand that it is wrong and that "argv" is an array of pointers to a string. I also tried to add asterisk but it brought back "1" (byte) as a result because I said "go to that address" and it showed me the size of the first element of each command-line argument. 
So, how can I solve this problem without many and many loops, just with "sizeof" function?

UPD: Sorry for that "%s" mistake. In the actual code I didn't write it.

And I DO understand that sizeof() won't bring me the size of array. I was pointing to the combination "sizeof() / sizeof (char)"

Also, thank you very much for "strlen" reminder. I am studying now. I don't know C language yet. Sorry, for my stupid mistakes.

Comment: What do you mean by "the size of elements of each command-line argument"?

Can you provide an example?

Comment: You have to use a function that gives you the length of a c-string, sizeof will always return the size of the pointer.

Comment: `sizeof` is *not* intended to give you a string's size. Actually `sizeof` is evaluated at compilation time so that can't work at all. Use `strlen` (in cstring) or `std::string::size` (in string) instead.

Answer (score 3):

You are printing the size of a character pointer. Instead you want the length of the string. You can use the standard function `strlen` :

( note: `argv[0]` is the program name itself, so 1st number indicates the length of program name.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("%zu\n", strlen(argv[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first thing this will print will be length of the program name which may not be what you want.

Comment: updating the answer..@ChrisDrew

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sizeof` use `strlen()` that returns the size of a string while excluding the string termination character from the counting. More information here: [Strlen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen)

Answer (score 0):

As it is seen from your program more preciseky from the declaration of the main arguments have type `char *`. That is they are pointers to first characters of strings that are passed to the program like arguments.

So you need to use standard C function `strlen` declared in header `<string.h>` to determine the size of the string passed like an argumnet.
Take into account that the last pointer in the array argv has value NULL.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for ( char **p = argv; *p; ++p )
    {
        printf( "%zu\n", strlen( *p ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```